# How do I find all of my posts on Google+?

Tags: google-plus, user-interface

My profile page on Google Plus lists all of my posts. [This is my profile page](https://plus.google.com/+EvanCarrollTheGreat/posts). However, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to see this Wall-equivalent from the web interface of plus.google.com.

Is it possible to log into plus.google.com and to view all of your posts using only the mouse? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see three different methods:

1. click your profile icon in the upper right, then click "Profile"
2. pull down the menu in the upper left (defaults to "Home") and click "Profile"
3. point your browser to https://plus.google.com/me

Comment: This only shows me private/public posts, NOT community posts ... any way to see those?

Comment: @Ze'ev: I don't believe Community posts existed at the time. Either way, that sounds like [a good question to ask](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I found the answer: https://plus.google.com/+BrianGlick/posts/CeNhYFivMC4